# Create 3D model of text with rounded/filleted or beveled corners

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry, mesh

I am trying to programmatically create the 3D model of text with beveled or rounded corners. See the following image for an example.
Another requirement is speed. It should be possible to create a model for a 10 letter word in less than 10s.

[image]

OpenScad is to slow.

I also tried Freecad, but the Freecad filleting algorithmus (which is from Opencascade) requires that the shortest line of a glyph is longer than the fillet radius. This would exclude nearly all fonts.
With freecad I also tried to create rounded corners by sweeping along the glyph paths with a profile. While the results did look good and speed was ok I was not able to create a valid solid out of it.

Are there any other libs to do this job? Is there a library to smooth corners in a mesh? 
Python as language would be preferred, but I would use anything else also.
As output format anything which can be converted to STL would be fine.

Comment: 1. why don't  you code it yourself? 2. speed is not an issue you can create mesh for each character, store it and then just use ti at runtime ... 3. I would do a Voxel map per character then smooth the corners (via filtering), then use the edge point as mesh control points for some curved surface like Bezier , or just chunky quads/triangles with smooth normal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try an alternative FreeCAD approach. When the problem are the short edges of the glyphs then you can approximate such a multi-edge wire with a single-edge spline. The resulting solid can be filled at will (ok, still dependent on the font and the sizes etc..)

Assuming your exampole, the "O", is a FreeCAD shapestring called "ShapeString":

```
w1 = App.ActiveDocument.ShapeString.Shape.Wires[0]
w2 = App.ActiveDocument.ShapeString.Shape.Wires[1]

f1 = Draft.makeBSpline(w1.discretize(30), True)
f2 = Draft.makeBSpline(w2.discretize(30), True)

f = f1.Shape.cut(f2.Shape)
pad = f.extrude(App.Vector(0,0,3))
Part.show(pad)
```

This does of course require some tweaking to work with all glyphs. Also you may need to increase the number of discretization points to get an exact result, dependend on your needs.

Other ways for approximation:

- the FreeCAD Wire object also has a approximate function, but I do not know the parameters meaning

[image: The example "0" approximated with BSplines]

Comment: Thank you for the idea and source snippet for this approach. The freecad makeFillet algorithmus seems to have problems with to small radii also. But if the number of discretization points is not to high the radii are ok. Will have to experiment a bit with different values. And find a algo which creates correct shapes from splines for glyphs like '8' or 'ö' ...

Comment: Hello @tobltobs, did you eventually end up with a nice solution for more corner cases such as 8 and ö?

Comment: Under Blender, what I do (manually) is create Text, type text, choose font, try to use the Text bevel's slider.. if it does not work well (ie. some vertex pop up far away from the mesh for an R character..), instead tune Text's extrude setting, then convert object to mesh (Alt+C), go into edit mode and Remove doubles for all meshes, then Make normals consistent, get out of edit mode, add a Remesh modifier with "Remove disconnected pieces" untoggled, add Subsurf modifier, add a Smooth modifier.